# I can't download Android licensing sample in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-lvl

I don't see Android licensing sample
[image]

The left side is how it should look.
My SDK is on the right  side. No licensing sample there.
Thanks

Comment: maybe it just downloads the sample and it does not have a separate sdk platform just for licensing. Check if sample exists by creating an app from samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Select 'Packages' menu, then 'Reload'

Comment: Nop. It did not help. I have discovered that I have installed another SDK Manager on another drive. I found Licensing example there. But it is a mistery why no licensing download in my first SDK Manager. Maybe I have to delete the both and reinstall them. Thanks .

Comment: There are source files in /extras/google/market_licensing/library/ . I don't know how to compile them to a library. Or should I add these sourses to my project? Oh, headache!

Answer (score 0):

Also you may want to select show updates/new packages and show installed packages.

Btw. I think it is called Google Play now instead of Google Market.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not understand what to do. I played with all menus in SDK Manager.

Comment: Okay. I found licensing_package. There is a sample application. But there are no libraries. How can get them please?

Comment: There are source files in /extras/google/market_licensing/library/ . I don't know how to compile them to a library. Or should I add these sourses to my project? Oh, headache!